# C# - Remove Duplicate lines

Tags: c#

I try to remove duplicate line within two different ArrayList.
here is my code:

```
 ArrayList URLs = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList Duplicated = new ArrayList();
 byte[] data = wc.DownloadData("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + keyword);
                MatchCollection M = Regex.Matches(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length), "[a-z]+[:][/][/][a-z]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-z]+");
                foreach (Match m in M)
                    Duplicated.Add(m.Value);
                foreach (string line in Duplicated)
                    URLs.Add(line);
                for (int i = 0; i < Duplicated.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (URLs.Contains(Duplicated[i]))
                        URLs.Remove(Duplicated[i]);
                }
                foreach (string line in URLs)
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(line + "\r\n");
```

Comment: Do not use `ArrayList`. Use `List<T>`. That said, don't use a list at all for this, there is no need.

Comment: then how can I remove Duplicated lines in this case?

Comment: Easily: `var urls =  (from Match m in M select m.Value).Distinct();`

Comment: Change `ArrayList` to `List<string>`. Then use `foreach (string line in URLs.Except(Duplicated))`

Comment: Read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to remove the duplicated, have a dictionary with a count, then select only items that have a count of 1.

```
 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> items = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>();
 byte[] data = wc.DownloadData("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + keyword);
 MatchCollection M = Regex.Matches(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length), "[a-z]+[:][/][/][a-z]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-z]+");
 foreach (Match m in M)
 {
     if ( items.ContainsKey(m.Value) )
         items[m.Value] += 1;
     else
         items.Add(m.Value, 1);
 }

 System.Collections.Generic.List<string> noDups = items.Where(b => b.Value == 1).Select(c => c.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: had a typo on the where clause

Comment: This is a lot of code to do something really basic. Also, use the indexer.

Comment: i used a dictionary...it has an indexer...@aluan...your recommendation is wrong because he asks to REMOVE duplicates...not to have distinct records...that's not the same thing

Comment: You're correct about the logic, but you should use the indexer `items[m.Value] = 1;`

Comment: its the same thing

Comment: Typo: `items[m.Value] += 1` instead of `items(m.Value) += 1`

Comment: Actually you can use it in both branches.

Comment: `TryGetValue` would be faster than the way you use `Contains` and `[]`.